# Authlogic active field to activated_at field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authlogic

is it possible to use the activeted_at field instead of the "active" field, since I need to know the account activation date, I can fill in the activated_at field through the callback, but for example, it will not be used during authentication, but I need this field to be used, is it possible to do?

Answer (score 0):

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  def active?
    activated_at.present?
  end
end
```

See the documentation on [magic states](https://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic/blob/5e0253dcd91ea72c9a5acc5f62590142b7f4bdb4/lib/authlogic/session/base.rb#L272).